# Streaming jquery(JS files) from a CDN (Google)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, http

This one is a case of not doing your homework.:-)

Apart from dynamic loading advantage, does it make sense to include a JavaScript library(jQuery in my case ) from a Google server when I can load it from my server as a single file comprised of the 19kb jQuery zip file + the additional JavaScript code I have written – all compressed with a JS compressor and served HTTP deflated.

With Google server I’ll have 2(parallel) HTTP round trips. One to get the jquery file and the other to get the site JavaScript code. One 19kb and the other say 20-25kb. 
Under normal circumstances it would be a single 30-35kb download from my site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider that a jQuery script downloaded from the google CDN might well already be cached on a visitor's browser, since it has consistent headers and cache control no matter where it is downloaded from. Hence, on average most users will only have to download your site-specific javascript scripts. Also, CDN generally have faster response times than single servers, since they respond from a server nearest to your location.

There is no cut and dry answer to your question, as both approaches offer good performance on modern connections. You should profile your system under duress and see what solution offers the best results (and if such optimization is even needed).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure scripts would be downloaded in parallel? [This example from Cuzillion](http://stevesouders.com/cuzillion/?c0=hj1hfff2_0&c1=hj1hfff2_0&t=1227551978929) seems to be saying that only IE8 can do that.

Also worth finding out is how many of your pageviews are first time visitors and how many have visited the site before to help you decide how much caching will influence download time. If you have a significant number of first time visitors it's probably worth skewing it in their favour to make the first time experience as fast as possible.

Comment: +1 for finding out your visitor profile. UX research shows that many users jump in and out of websites based on search results, not navigating around individual sites. The speed of the first page render for a first-time visitor to your site can make a big difference on whether they stick around for more or give up and go back to the search engine.

Answer (score 1):

A benchmark test done by httpwatch for js files from google.

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/11/27/google-adds-https-support-to-the-ajax-libraries-api/

Answer (score 0):

Is this a real question? Just make sure your Cache-Control in your HTTP headers are properly configured and the end user's client will only pull it once. This is an absolutely trivial amount of data.

Comment: Even with cache control + ET tag a new user will have to download 30kb of data.

Comment: Cherian, this page alone is 27.61kb. Unless you're expecting users to hit-and-run with one or two page views, each rendered page will quickly end up outweighing the size of your jslibs. Either way, even with 10000 users that's 30 MEGS. If your server can't serve that, get a new one.

Comment: That should read 1000 users not 10000. Got a little happy with my zero key.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there isn't any real downside to using a well-known [jQuery CDN](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) (such as Google's), and there are some potential upsides, so my personal preference is to take the CDN approach. If nothing else, that's one less file for me to have to worry about and maintain as part of my source tree.

There are several advantages I see to using a CDN vs. a single fat JavaScript archive:

- Reducing latency for retrieving uncached resources, since these assets are served from edge locations
- For 3rd-party scripts, the user's browser probably already has them cached and won't have to download them again for your site.
- Working around per-host browser limitations for parallel requests, by distributing your assets across multiple hostnames (of course, this can also be done via your own servers using simple subdomain tricks).
- Reducing overall load on your primary servers, esp. important during peak usage periods or YC/Slashdot "attacks".

When to care about download time for HTML page assets:

- When you have a significant number of first-time visitors (from search engines and/or social media). Research shows that people aren't very patient these days, so you really need to go out of your way to make a good first impression. (See also Jakob Nielsen's articles on [Page Abandonment](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/page-abandonment-time.html), [Answer Engines](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20040816.html) and [Response Times](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/response-times.html).)
- For visitors using mobile devices. Mobile data networks are often slow and/or congested.
- For shops practicing continuous delivery and causing frequent churn in assets (more common for brand-new sites and apps)

*P.S. - Aaron Hopkins has one of the best write-ups on [optimizing page load time](http://www.die.net/musings/page_load_time/) I've seen. A bit dated, but still quite relevant.*

*P.S.S. - You might want to take a look at Zepto, a light-weight (24K vs 100K), api-compatible alternative to [jQuery](http://zeptojs.com/).*